# My routing module don't find my component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to apply lazy loading in my application, but i receive:

> Uncaught Error: Component CustofixoComponent is not part of any
>   NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

custofixo.module.ts:

```
import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusaoModule } from './../../dialogexclusao/dialog-confirmacao-exclusao.module';
//Importação de módulos angular
import { MyMaterialDesignModule } from '../../../app.materialdesign.module';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxCurrencyModule } from "ngx-currency";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoadingModule } from '../../loading/loading.module';
import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask'
import { MostraToastService } from '../../../services/mostratoast.service';
import { CustoFixoRoutingModule } from './custofixo.routing.module';
//Importação de componentes do módulo
import { CustofixoComponent } from './custofixo.component';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';
import { CustosService } from '../../../services/custos.service';
import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusao } from '../../dialogexclusao/dialog-exclusao.component';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
import { svgInfoManModule } from '../../svgInfoMan/svgInfoMan.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CustoFixoRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    LoadingModule,
    MyMaterialDesignModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DialogConfirmacaoExclusaoModule,
    NgxCurrencyModule,
    NgxMaskModule,
    svgInfoManModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    CustofixoComponent
  ],
  declarations: [CustofixoComponent],
  entryComponents:[DialogConfirmacaoExclusao],
  providers:[
    CustosService,
    MostraToastService,
    AuthService
  ]
})

export class CustoFixoModule { }
```

custofixo.routing.ts: the error is generated in **this file**. I don't know why my routing don't find my component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustofixoComponent } from './custofixo.component';




    const custoFixoRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', component: CustofixoComponent
        }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(custoFixoRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class CustoFixoRoutingModule {}
```

In my root routes:

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'dash', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
    { path: '', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module#BemVindoModule' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module#BemVindoModule' },
    { path: 'custofixo', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/custofixo/custofixo.module#CustoFixoModule' }
```

The bemvindomodule works well, but my custoFixoModule have a similar code and don't work.

Restart ng server still don't work

Comment: add component name also in children array with path and loadChildren

Comment: @ashishpal you can put a example?

Comment: something like this:  `{ path: ' ',component: CustofixoComponent, loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module#BemVindoModule' }`

Comment: Did you import the custofixo.module in the main module?

Comment: @itsundefined no

Comment: @ashishpal tried to add component but still receive the message that is not part of any ngmodule

Comment: in root module, you should import the module, from where bootstrapping starts

Comment: if i import my module in app module i don't will lose the benefits from the lazy loading? lol, the documentation from the angular says that i don't have import the lazy load modules in app module

Comment: I have never used lazy loading. Sorry for that thought. Maybe the fact that you have typed : `exports:[
    CustofixoComponent
  ]` there is a problem?

Comment: No, i try to remove from the exports and still have a message error. My bemvindoModule too export the component and works

Comment: share your class where you defined dashboard routes.

Comment: Please create a minimum reproduction on stackblitz if possible. I also notice that you are giving path to loadChildren starting with `src`, try giving it a relative path, something starting with `./`

Comment: @SachinGupta i change to ./ but still error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import lazy loaded module into another module. You can move the component to shared module and import that module in lazyloaded modules

```
AppModule
SharedModule
LazyLoadedModule1 - SharedModule
LazyLoadedModule2 - SharedModule
LazyLoadedModule3 - SharedModule
```

Comment: I'm not importing lazy loading modules in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not declared the component `CustofixoComponent` anywhere. You need to add it in the declarations array of the `CustoFixoModule`.

Comment: In my CustoFixoModule i already do this. look my code. declarations: [CustofixoComponent],

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds

try to break `serve` and rerun because sometimes cli don't detect the files

### OR

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    LoadingModule,
    MyMaterialDesignModule,
    CustoFixoRoutingModule, <--- here
    HttpClientModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DialogConfirmacaoExclusaoModule,
    NgxCurrencyModule,
    NgxMaskModule,
    svgInfoManModule,
  ]
```

I have read somewhere that order will considered on building the angular app

Comment: Changed the order and restart ngserve, but i still receive the warning

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated `custofixo.routing.ts` file from which the error is thrown:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustofixoComponent } from './custofixo.component';
const custoFixoRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full', // <-- Add pathMatch and check again
    component: CustofixoComponent
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(custoFixoRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustoFixoRoutingModule { }
```

For more details, please check [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects)